# how i can introduce a image into of PDF generated with weasyprint?

Tags: html, django, weasyprint

I can generate a PDF using Django and weasyprint, but, i have a problem with a html, when i need load to image, then, i get a error. My implementation is it:

[This is my implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWdEs.png)

and my html, i call the image with a simple

"img src="{{ constancia.imagencita.url }} "

and i get "/media/firmas_directores_rrhh/180px-Walt_Disney_1942_signature.svg.png" (Pixbuf error: Unrecognized image file format)"

Answer (score 4):

I was able to solve this issue using an absolute file path with the "file:///" prefix as the URL.

Not unlike:

```
<img src="file:///path/to/file.png">
```